# tidytext Error: Can't convert a function to a quosure

Tags: r, tidytext

I am starting to use tidytext to get basic word frequencies for a text file with a collection of emails and lots of garbage in between.

The relevant part of the script is:

```
library(tidytext)

data <- read_lines("emails.txt")

text_tibble <- tibble(line = seq_along(data), text = data)

text_tibble %>%
        unnest_tokens_(word, text)
```

> Error: Can't convert a function to a quosure

Can you please orient me?
Thanks.
[Original data](https://www.dropbox.com/s/v61f70yg1l3ez7p/emails.txt?dl=0)
[result of dput(text_tibble)](https://www.dropbox.com/s/rp3zkkbzz5nt2e4/emails2.txt?dl=0)

Comment: please provide your data in the form of `dput(text_tibble)`

Comment: This is still not optimal. What I meant is run `dput(text_tibble)` in your console and copy and paste the output into your question. Please check this question for tips on asking a reproducible question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: I wonder if they have `unnest_token_()` in the tidytext package. Have you tried `unnest_token()`, instead?

Comment: Thanks jazzuro, I was not familiar with unnest_token and it worked, but I still do not know why I got the error. I guess I will have to research it later.

Comment: @user9365328 The package does not have `unnest_token_()'. You might have thought that the function was in the dplyr package, maybe?

Comment: yes I used to use that with dplyr but I swear I used it with tidytext too. Maybe I am wrong, I have not done this kind of script in some time.

Answer (score 0):

The tidytext package does have underscored versions of most functions for standard evaluation, although [these are being deprecated](https://github.com/juliasilge/tidytext/blob/master/R/tidytext.R#L19) in favor of tidyeval semantics.

The idea with the underscored versions is that they take arguments by value, not by code like the usual non-standard evaluation versions that we are mostly used to using, like with dplyr. If you wanted to use the underscored versions (which, like I said, are being deprecated) you need to pass the actual values.

```
text_tibble %>%
    unnest_tokens_("word", "text")
```